# bottom-right corner of border is missing?

Tags: html, css

I have borders on the left and right sides of some items in a list, but I'm getting these white gaps that I don't want, but it's only on the right side which is weird and I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be great. 
The code:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 21px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
}
ul li:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}
ul li:hover li {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
ul li:hover li.top {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
ul li:hover li.bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #939393;
}
ul li ul.dropdown {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="font-size: 16px; width: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 4px;">
  <li><a href="#"><u>Products</u></a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="top"><a href="#">Apples</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Cans</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Bowls</a>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom"><a href="#">Cups</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style in ul li

```
border: 1px solid white;
```

is causing extra white lines to be drawn

Remove it and you should be good

Comment: That avoids this problem, but then that causes the other items on the page to move b/c the borders make the item bigger when it's added which is why I had white borders there by default.

Comment: Yeah you are right the border helps keep the items from shifting. If you are willing to live with a set height on the items. Using box-sizing: border-box will make it easy for the border to be drawn on the inside. Added a jsfiddle with an example http://jsfiddle.net/0aao8071/1/